# WPF ControlTemplate AND DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, controltemplate

I have `ListView` where I would like to apply a custom `ControlTemplate` to it's items. It is defined like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyAwesomeItems}" ...
```

MyAwesomeItems holds different classes. So I thought to myself: "Well, hello DataTemplates."

To make the contained items look the way I want them to, I have defined a `ControlTemplate` like this:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
          <Border><ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/></Border>
        </ControlTemplate>            
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I have used `ContentControl` with Binding to `TemplateBinding Content`. I expected that WPF would then insert my items inside that `ContentControl`, using whatever DataTemplate I have defined for it.

But instead, it looks like WPF just uses the items `.ToString()` and does not apply any DataTemplates. Is this intended behaviour?

What I want to achieve is: Have a **list of items**, where the **container of each item** looks exactly the way I want and the **content** of that container comes from the DataTemplate.

Comment: Use a `ContentPresenter` instead. The difference is in how the `DataContext` is set.

Comment: It does not matter. Same result.

Comment: I forgot to mention: don't set `Content`! Just use `<ContentPresenter/>`.

Comment: Wonderful! It works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To understand why it works: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.contentsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `ControlTemplate` for a `ContentControl` you usually use an empty `ContentPresenter` tag. In your case:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Border>
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The `ContentPresenter` has a `ContentSource` property which defaults to "Content" and sets all the necessary properties (`Content`, `ContentTemplate`, etc.).

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.contentsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.